# Check if an enum has a field that equals a string

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum

```
public enum FileExtentions {
    mp3,
    mpeg
}
```

And I have a FileInfo of which I want to check if the extension is in the previous enum.
I was hoping I could do a

```
FileExtensions.Any(e=>e.ToString().Equals(file.Extension));
```

But that would have been too awesome.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What's the reason behind `Any` … `Equals`? Did you overlook `Contains`?

```
bool result = Enum.GetNames(typeof(FileExtensions)).Contains("mp3");
```

Answer (score 10):

While pressing submit I thought of the answer myself:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(FileExtensions)).Any(f=>f.Equals("."+file.Extension))
```

Comment: But you can't mark your own entry as answer. But that's logical I guess.

Comment: file.Extension has the leading period - not the enum names. Shouldn't that be (f => ("." + f).Equals(file.Extension))?

Comment: You post helped me find an answer for my problem also:

public enum Something { John, Rob, Tim }

var msg = "I like Tim, he is good";
            
var isOk = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Something)).Any(x => msg.Contains(x.ToString()));

Answer (score 2):

[Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) will take a string containing the name of an enum value. The only ugliness is that you have to strip the leading period off of [File.Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension.aspx) and it's case sensitive:

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(FileExtension), file.Extension.Substring(1).ToLower())
```

Edit: Extension method goodness to get close to your desired syntax:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNames(this Type t) {
   if (!t.IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException();

   return Enum.GetNames(t);
}

typeof(FileExtensions).GetNames().Any(e=>e.ToString().Equals(file.Extension));
```

Personally, though, I'd still rather the IsDefined route:

```
bool IsDefined(this Type t, string name) {
   if (!t.IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException();

   return Enum.IsDefined(t, name);
}

typeof(FileExtension).IsDefined(file.Extension);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the FileInfo type with the following extension method:

```
public static bool HasExtension(this FileInfo file)
{
    var ext = file.Extension.StartsWith(".") ? file.Extension.Substring(1) 
                                             : file.Extension;

    return Enum.GetNames(typeof(FileExtensions))
               .Any(f => f.Equals(ext));
}
```

and use it like:

```
bool hasExtension = file.HasExtension();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the System.Enum type:

```
string extension = Enum.GetName(typeof(FileExtensions), FileExtensions.mp3);

if (extension == file.Extension)
  // do something here
```

**Update:**

Ah, I misunderstood that you want to check the entire enum for the extension and not that a specific enum value matches the extension. In that case, your approach with *GetNames()* is the route - sorry you can't mark your own answer as accepted for your own question. ;-)

Comment: That would check if my file has that exact extension. If I wanted to check that, I could aswell do if(file.Extension.equals(FileExtensions.Mp3.ToString()) [untested]

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Enum.IsDefined function. It pretty easy, in your case:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(FileExtentions), file.Extension))
```

Comment: Check @Mark Brackett answer

Answer (score 0):

General solution:

```
Enum.IsDefined(Type, Object)
```

Your solution is:

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(FileExtentions), FileInfo)
```